# How to avoid reinstalling ruby each time I restart?

Tags: software-installation, ruby, rails

I need to do something with Ruby on Rails, so I have followed [this guide](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10) to set up my development environment.

I used the RVM method to install Ruby, then I install Rails as shows in the guide. I run both `ruby -v` and `rails -v` and they give me the expected output, I do my stuff using rails and everything is ok.

Problem is that when I restart my machine nor Ruby or Rails is installed, I have to install them back everytime I restart. Do you know what could be the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that its not just RVM not being started ?

Check `.rvm/scripts/rvm` exists in your home directory.

If it does, then its probably not being started, check in your `.bashrc` for lines below.
If they are not there you need to add the calls to initialise RVM in your `.bashrc` by running the following command:

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Based on instructions from: http://sirupsen.com/get-started-right-with-rvm/

Comment: Thanks a lot man, .rvm/scripts/rvm exits and I added this command at the end of .bashrc and it solved my problem. Have a nice day.